# RCA VCR Fuse Question

Tags: power-supply, power, fuses

I have an old RCA VCR (model number VR501) which contains a fuse in the power supply I am repairing. From the markings on the fuse I can only tell that it is a 1.6A 250VAC glass 5x20mm fuse, however I am not sure how to tell if it is a slow-blow or fast-blow. There is no available service manual for it that I can find either. Would anyone know which of these it would be?